# integer expression expected shell scripting - BASH

Tags: sql, bash, oracle

I am trying to get the LAG between Primary & Standby database using the below shell script. The query works fine returning the values "DATABASE IS OUTOFSYNC" or "DATABASE IS INSYNC" for an instance that has 1 Node which returns a single value, but I get an error "[: 0 1: integer expression expected" for an instance that has two Nodes which returns two values for the LAG on the first Node and the Second Node.

So here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_status=$(sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" <<EOF
       
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
       
SELECT prim.seq - tgt.seq seq_gap
           
FROM
           
(
       
SELECT thread#, MAX(sequence#) seq, MAX(completion_time) tm
       
FROM
       
v\$archived_log
       
GROUP BY
       
thread#
       
) 
           
prim,
      
(
      
SELECT thread#, MAX(sequence#) seq, MAX(completion_time) tm
          
FROM
          
v\$archived_log
          
WHERE
          
dest_id IN 
          
(
          
SELECT
          
dest_id
          
FROM
          
v\$archive_dest
          
WHERE
      
target = 'STANDBY'
          
)
      
AND 
          
applied = 'YES'
          
GROUP BY
          
thread#
      
) 
          
tgt
          
WHERE
      
prim.thread# = tgt.thread#;
      
exit;

EOF

)

if [ "$get_status" -ge 5 ]; then
    
echo "DATABASE IS OUTOFSYNC"

else
    
echo "DATABASE IS INSYNC"

fi
```

Is there a better way to write this script?

After adding `typeset -p get_status` after the query and before the if I get the below results:

```
declare -- get_status=" 1

0"

./dgtest2.sh: line 41: [: 1

0: integer expression expected

DATABASE IS INSYNC
```

The query is returning more than one value/string (for 2 nodes or threads) as shown in picture/screenshot and it seems like my script is only coded to address a single value/string generated by the query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYG4M.png)

Is there away to modify the script to address multiple values/strings generated by the query

The logic should be if all values returned are `-ge 5` it should report `"DATABASE IS OUTOFSYNC"` else `"DATABASE IS INSYNC"` for all values returned are `-lt 5`.

The logic for one value `-lt 5` and one value `-ge 5` would not suffice as the values constantly change on the database.

Any values from `0 - 4` that the database returns whether from both Nodes should report as `"DATABASE IS INSYNC"` and any value from `5 upwards` that the database returns whether from both Nodes should report as `"DATABASE IS OUTOFSYNC"`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd expect syntax errors here...)

Comment: I use Oracle version 12.2.0.1.0 hosted on AIX 7200-04-01-1939

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to capture the status values (returned by the `sqlplus` script) into an array and then loop through the array testing said status values.

Instead of:

```
variable=$(sqlplus ...)
```

We want:

```
variable=( $(sqlplus ...) )
```

For OP's current scripting, with a name change for the variable, we will replace this:

```
get_status=$(sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" <<EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT prim.seq - tgt.seq seq_gap
... 
exit;
EOF
)
```

With this:

```
status_array=( $(sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" <<EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT prim.seq - tgt.seq seq_gap
...
exit;
EOF
) )
```

One idea for the follow-on logic testing:

- default database status is `INSYNC`
- if any status values are `-ge 5` then set database status to `OUTOFSYNC`

The code for this looks like:

```
db_status='INSYNC'

for status in "${status_array[@]}"
do
    [[ "${status}" -ge 5 ]] && db_status='OUTOFSYNC' && break
done

echo "DATABASE IS ${db_status}"
```

I'm not setup to run the `sqlplus` script but I should be able to simulate the results with the following array assignments:

```
status_array=(1)
status_array=(7)
status_array=(0 1)
status_array=(5 7)
status_array=(5 3)
```

Running our code for each of these array assignments gives us:

```
##################### status_array=(1)

DATABASE is INSYNC

##################### status_array=(7)

DATABASE is OUTOFSYNC

##################### status_array=(0 1)

DATABASE is INSYNC

##################### status_array=(5 7)

DATABASE is OUTOFSYNC

##################### status_array=(5 3)

DATABASE is OUTOFSYNC
```

Comment: Tested in our environment and this worked perfectly. Thanks much appreciated!